# Voltage on a Transmission Line with Ideal Conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, electromagnetic, microwave, conductors

Let's consider a transmission line with Perfect Electric Conductors.

We know that if an external AC source is applied, we get a voltage waveform between the conductors which is function of the position (and also of time, but focus on the first dependence).

But we know that in a perfect electric conductor the electric field is orthogonal to its surface, and this means that its surface is equipotential. This property is true in any situation (steady state or not), because the tangential electric field is always 0 in a perfect electric conductor.

The following picture shows clearly that E is orthogonal to the conductors' surface.
[enter link description here](https://i.ibb.co/MMcYy4B/IMG-20191127-092628.jpg)

But this seems in contrast with the fact that the voltage depends on the position.

Which is the solution?

Comment: I guess if characteristic impedance is 0, you get infinite wavelength having flat voltage profile.

Comment: The electric field here is not only due to a scalar potential, there is a magnetic vector potential as well, which complicates the matter: E=- V - ∂A/∂t.

Comment: And is this magnetic potential vector present each time we work in AC?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo, assuming you know some vector calculus. The vector potential A is defined such that the magnetic induction B is its' curl (B = xA). Defining A is possible because the B field is divergence free (meaning no magnetic charge exists).The time derivative of A (so yes, AC) is also a source of the E field. That is why it is called vector potential, as opposed to scalar potential.

Comment: Perfect. So, we say that: E=- V - ∂A/∂t. In this condition, does E keep normal to the conductors' surface? In theory it is possible, at this point:  V = E - ∂A/∂t and so, also if along the surface we have E = 0,  V is not 0 because of - ∂A/∂t, and so there may be a variation of V along the conductors'. Is this true?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo I think you could say that, yes. The fact that E is perpendicular to the conductors is a boundary condition being imposed by assuming the conductors are perfect. If I find some time maybe I will try to write an answer based on this.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when we defined the electrostatic potential difference (aka "voltage"),

$$V=-\int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec\ell,$$

we called it the **electrostatic** potential difference because it is only strictly valid in electrostatics. When we use this concept in AC circuits, we're using it as an approximation only (usually described as the *lumped circuit* approximation). In particular, in the presence of time-varying magnetic fields, we can't count on this \$V\$ to be independent of the path over which we take the integral.

In transmission lines, we are definitely dealing with time-varying magnetic fields, so we can't expect the electrostatic potential difference to be well defined.

We define an approximate potential at a point along the transmission line as the negative integral of the electric field from one conductor to the other at that point.

But we can't expect to get the same result (because this isn't an electrostatics situation) if we take an integral from some point on the first conductor, lengthwise along the conductor (with contribution 0, because the material is p.e.c.), across the gap at another location, and then back along the second conductor (again contributing 0) to the point opposite where we started.

Meaning, if we take the integral to calculate the "voltage" across the transmission line at position \$z=0\$, we can't expect this integral to be the same at \$z=z_1\$ just because there's no electric field within the conductors.

Answer (score 0):

You’re driving with AC. You can’t ignore time-varying effects.

The line has a distributed capacitance: there’s different charge densities at points with different E fields and potentials.

Since the E and potential at each point varies with time, so does the charge: there are time-varying currents to change those charges.

Those in turn cause time varying B fields around the conductors.

And the additional E fields induced by those time-varying B fields re what you’re looking for.

Comment: So is the electric field not orthogonal to the surfaces?

Comment: The E field is both always perpendicular to the conductor _and_ varying with space and time. The space- and time-varying aspects work together.

Comment: But if it keeps orthogonal to the surface (also if it varies in intensity with space and time), why should the potential be different at different positions? In theory, if we move from z1 to z2, we do not have work because E is orthogonal, so we should have V(z1) = V(z2)

Answer (score 0):

> But we know that in a perfect electric conductor the electric field is orthogonal to its surface, and this means that its surface is equipotential.

It's probably better to flip it around and say 'when the surface is equipotential, the electric field will be orthogonal to (normal to) its surface'.

In a transmission line, which you can model as having distributed inductance, no matter how perfect the conductor, the voltage along the inductor clearly varies with position if the transmission line is carrying anything other than DC. The surface is not equipotential, the electric field is not normal to the surface.

When dealing with transmission lines, AC makes my head hurt, I prefer to launch a step along it, and see the change of voltage along the line together with the change of current charging the line.

Comment: My doubt is about the sentence: "the electric field is not normal to the surface". If you look at the picture in the link, it is normal to the surface. If you consider TEM mode in a coaxial cable, the Electric Field is radial and so normal to the surface. And in transmission lines EM analysis starting from Maxwell Equations I always see the condition: E normal to conductors' surface

Comment: 'if you look at the picture in the link' - have you considered the possibility that the picture is not 100% correct, but has been approximated to avoid complication. Do you accept that the voltage will be different at different points along the transmission line?

Comment: @Neil_UK "The surface is not equipotential, the electric field is not normal to the surface." - I don't want to hurt your head any further, but that is a non sequitor. The electric field is still perpendicular by virtue of the boundary condition that I mentioned in my answer. It's just that in the case of time varying fields,  the scalar potential is not only related to the electric field vector, but also to the magnetic vector potential. The electric field is no longer conservative, but it's summation with the first time derivative of the vector potential is.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field being perpendicular to the conductor surfaces is a boundary condition imposed by their perfect conductance. The electric field lines terminate in the surface charge density according to $$ n \cdot \varepsilon \mathbf E = \sigma  \space\space(1)$$ with *n* the normal vector to the surface, and σ the surface charge density.
The question is now how  a potential gradient can exist along the conductor surface while the electric field strength is normally incident.

A give-away is one of Maxwell's equations (Faraday's law): $$\nabla × \mathbf E + \frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} = 0\space\space(2)$$ which essentially tells us that the electric field is non-conservative in the presence of a time-varying magnetic field. Let's study this a bit more in depth.

From vector calculus we know that the divergence of a curl and the curl of a gradient are both zero: $$\nabla \cdot (\nabla × \mathbf A) = 0\space\space(3)$$  $$\nabla × (\nabla V) = 0\space\space(4)$$

As far as we know there is no magnetic charge, so according to Gauss' law for magnetic fields the magnetic induction has zero divergence:

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf B =0$$
which allows us to use the identity of (3) to define a vector **A** such that $$  \mathbf B = \nabla × \mathbf A\space\space(5)$$
We call **A** the magnetic vector potential. Substituting (5) in (2) gives 
$$ \nabla ×( \mathbf E  + \frac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial t}) = 0$$ Now the identify of (4) allows us again to define the non-static electric scalar potential

$$ \mathbf E  + \frac{\partial \mathbf A}{\partial t} = -\nabla \varphi$$ which shows that a potential gradient can exist that does not have the same direction as the electric field vector, as long as there is a time varying magnetic vector potential, so there really is no contradiction that the potential gradient can be at angles with the electric field.